# .net core logging - Only record log type of warning and above in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, logging, asp.net-core-webapi

I came across several article that talks about creating custom logger for .NET core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider

https://medium.com/codex/asp-net-core-6-logging-ad721d4b0cde

What I have:

**Program.CS:**

```
//Clear default log providers
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
```

**MyClass:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
    public MyClass(IConfiguration config, ILogger<UserIdFilterAttribute> logger)
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
        }
      
 ...
 ....

       _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, "This is a test");
       _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "This exception");
     }
```

**What I want:**

When I call _logger.Log(), I want messaged to be logged at two places.

1. All messages on Console
2. Log type of warning & above to be logged in SQL server.

How can I achieve this functioanlity?

Comment: You need to pick a logging Framework that supports all desired targets and then configure it accordingly. You can then choose if you want to keep using MS Logging API or the Framework-Specific one.

Answer (score 2):

You can [implement a custom logger and logging provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) to achieve your requirement. And the following simple sample demonstrate how to implement a custom logging provider, you can refer to it.

*MyCustomLoggerProvider class*

```
public class MyCustomLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        => new MyCustomLogger(categoryName);
}
```

*MyCustomLogger class*

```
public class MyCustomLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly string _categoryName;

    public MyCustomLogger(string categoryName)
        => _categoryName = categoryName;
    public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull => default!;

    //for testing purpose
    //you can implement IsEnabled method based on your requirement
    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true; 

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        logBuilder.Append($"{logLevel} {_categoryName}: {state}{(exception != null ? "\n" : string.Empty)}{exception}\n");

        Console.WriteLine(logBuilder.ToString());


        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Warning || logLevel == LogLevel.Error || logLevel == LogLevel.Critical)
        {
            //...
            //code logic to store log in db
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

*add logging provider*

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddProvider(new MyCustomLoggerProvider());
```

*write logs*

```
_logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Information...");
_logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, "Warning...");
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the attached link it shows you how to do it with SeriLog:
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3532012/how-to-use-serilog-to-log-application-data-to-sql-server-in-aspnet-core.html